# Do you gain combat advantage from a flanking charge?

Tags: dnd-4e, combat, charge

Can you gain combat advantage from flanking as the result of a charge? For example, if I charge an enemy, and will end my charge opposite an ally, do I get +2 for CA from flanking in addition to +1 for charge?

My guess would be no because I'm not adjacent to the enemy when I begin my charge attack. But the rules don't explicitly state this, so I wouldn't mind confirmation!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The charge special attack says you "make a melee basic attack" at the end of the movement. So, the damage-dealing attack is made when you're already in flianking position.

The same is true for every power that has you move before striking. You consider flanking positions the moment the to hit roll is rolled. If you're flanking in that moment, you get combat advantage against your target.

Comment: Ahhh yes, reread the entry for Charge. Excellent reminder to keep the order of "compound" actions in mind. So, am I correct in applying a total of +3 to hit?

Comment: @neologiker yes.